# How to retrieve data from a previous form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to disable a button in a form when the user is logged in as "operator" and enable it when he is an "admin". I have 3 form : first one => **login page** where I have the **"User" and "password"** parameters, second one => **menu** where I have a **label on the top** saying who is currently connect (operator or admin), third one => the **repair** **page**.

The problem is that when I click on the button "Back" on my third form, and I get back on the second form, the button **is enable**. So even "Operator" can access it through this glitch / bug.

Code for my login page:

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main form2 = new Main(this);
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=(local); Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT count(*) FROM Loginmdp WHERE util='" + textBox1.Text + "' AND mdp='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connexion réussie ! ");
                this.Hide();
                form2.Show();

                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Identifiant / Mot de passe faux. Veuillez resaisir votre identifiant et mot de passe.");

                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SQL EXCEPTION : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Here is my code for the menu :

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    private Login login;

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Main(Login login)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label3.Text = login.textBox1.Text;

        this.login = login;

        if (login.textBox1.Text == "admin" && login.textBox2.Text == "root")
        {
            button2.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Repair form3 = new Repair();
        this.Hide();

        form3.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Admin form4 = new Admin();
        this.Hide();
        form4.Show();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Login().Show();
        this.Hide();
        MessageBox.Show("Vous êtes déconnecté");
    }
}
```

Code for the repair page :

```
public partial class Repair : Form
{
    public Repair()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");

        maConnexion.Open();

         string Var1 = textBox1.Text;
         SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoardName", Var1);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", Var1);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNum", Var1);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FComponent", Var1);
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailOnly WHERE BoardName=@BoardName OR Machine=@Machine OR SerialNum=@SerialNum OR FComponent=@FComponent AND ReportingOperator != NULL";
         SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         sda.Fill(ds);
         dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Main ff = new Main();
        ff.Show();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       /**
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = string.Format("BoardName LIKE '%{0}%'",textBox1.Text.Replace("'","''"));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;**/
    }
}
```

Step by step pictures now :

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB5Oe.png)
[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h1TI.jpg)
[Third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4I6T.jpg)

Comment: You have to implement the 'view-model' class that will store the state of controls as necessary and will be accessible by all 3 forms...

Comment: What's that ? How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to define the 'view-model' class:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private static ViewModel viewModel;

    public static ViewModel Instance
    {
        get { return viewModel ?? (viewModel = new ViewModel()); }
    }

    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

Initialize it as a global variable (or any way you prefere the most), and use it in the Main form:

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    label3.Text = login.textBox1.Text;

    button2.Enabled = ViewModel.Instance.IsAdmin;        
}
```

The IsAdmin property should be set up in Login form:

```
....
    if (textBox1.Text == "admin" && textBox2.Text == "root")
    {
        ViewModel.Instance.IsAdmin = true;
    }
```

Comment: Can't do the .IsEnable, it say that the object references is required for the propriety, method or non static  field.

Comment: as i said just declare it globally 'static ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();'

Comment: The class need to be create in login or main ? Or in another specific form or file ?

Comment: return viewModel ?? (viewModel == new ViewModel());  is in red. i have the same error as in my first comment. :/ I'm sorry i'm just beginning in C#

Comment: viewModel should be static - i've corrected my answer again

Comment: i've corrected some things : public static void Instance() { return viewModel ?? (viewModel == new ViewModel());} is it right ? but still it say he can't apply ?? on a boolean and ViewModel.

Comment: no, it's not right (sorry i've made this answer without any check) - i've corrected the property definition in the answer...

Comment: not working either. Always the instance that is not working

Comment: omg, shame on me... now i've checked - the answer contains correct ViewModel definition

Comment: Sorry for the late reply was busy on another work ! Okay i dont have anymore the error ! but still he dont have the view on " button2.Enabled = ViewModel.Instance.IsEnabled;  " the ViewModel.Instance is not accepted. And IsEnabled is not define pour ViewModel.Instance but if i replace it by IsAdmin there is no more error on this line.

Comment: Okay edit : I've put in my form "Main" a using WindowsForm.Login and i've changed IsEnabled by IsAdmin and i dont have errors anymore in my code.

Comment: Edit : WORKING THANK YOU VERY MUCH !